# My epoll_wait can be triggered, but always return fd 0

Tags: c, linux-kernel, openwrt, epoll

I am tring to porting OpenWrt's ubus to MTK's 7620/7621, a mips platform. But it seems that the epoll in it can't work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <libubox/usock.h>

#ifndef EPOLLRDHUP
#define EPOLLRDHUP 0x2000
#endif

static int poll_fd = -1;

static int usage(const char *progname)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [<options>]\n"
        "Options: \n"
        "  -s <socket>:     Set the unix domain socket to listen on\n"
        "\n", progname);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *ubus_socket = UBUS_UNIX_SOCKET;
    int ret = 0;
    int ch;
    int fd, cfd;
    struct epoll_event ev;
    struct epoll_event evs = {0};

    poll_fd = epoll_create(32);
    if (poll_fd < 0) {
        perror("epoll create");
        ret = -1;
        goto out;
    }

    //fcntl(poll_fd, F_SETFD, fcntl(poll_fd, F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "s:")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 's':
            ubus_socket = optarg;
            break;
        default:
            return usage(argv[0]);
        }
    }

    unlink(ubus_socket);
    umask(0177);

    fd = usock(USOCK_UNIX | USOCK_SERVER | USOCK_NONBLOCK, ubus_socket, NULL);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("usock");
        ret = -1;
        goto out;
    } else {
        printf("sock fd %d\n", fd);
    }

    ev.data.fd = fd;
    ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLET;
    ret = epoll_ctl(poll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("epoll ctl");
        goto out;
    }

    while (1) {
        ret = epoll_wait(poll_fd, &evs, 1, -1);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("epoll wait");
            goto out;
        }

        if (ret > 0) {
            printf("wait for %d %x\n", ret, evs.events);
            if (evs.events & EPOLLIN) {
                printf("in fd %d\n", evs.data.fd);
                if (evs.data.fd == fd) {
                    cfd = accept(evs.data.fd, NULL, 0);
                    if (cfd < 0) {
                        perror("accept");
                        goto out;
                    }
                    printf("accept fd %d\n",cfd);
                }
            }
        }
    }

out:
    return ret;
}
```

The fd in epoll_event is 0 every time, which does not match ubus socket I created before. And the ptr in epoll_event's data is also always NULL, even I have added something into it after epoll_ctl(...,EPOLL_CTL_ADD,..).

```
The struct epoll_event is defined as :

           typedef union epoll_data {
               void    *ptr;
               int      fd;
               uint32_t u32;
               uint64_t u64;
           } epoll_data_t;

           struct epoll_event {
               uint32_t     events;    /* Epoll events */
               epoll_data_t data;      /* User data variable */
           };
```

My kernel version is 2.6.36.x.

Comment: A usage statement is not an error message.  If a user tries to execute `progname -t /p/a/t/h` a good error message is `-t: unknown option`.  Never write usage statements to stderr, because inevitably the usage statement will grow to be multiple pages and the user will try to pipe the output to a pager.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Because I link my application with an older version uclibc, but run with a higher one. So the syscall epoll_ctl and epoll_wait can't work correctly.